# Splitting Sentences in Python

Tags: python, split

Please input string: Python and Perl are programming languages

```
Python
Perl
and
are 
programming
languages
```

I want an input to be split but the upper case words go on top. I am thinking of using two lists: one with the title case words and one with lower. I am trying to use an if statement to place the words in a certain list. Please suggest some ideas!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your example output is wrong, because it would look like this:

```
Perl
Python
and
are
languages
programming
```

Sorting by capital first would result in `Perl` above `Python` because `e` comes first. Additionally, because uppercase comes first you can simply do

```
print "\n".join(sorted(a.split()))
```

to get the desired result.

**EDIT:** After rereading the question I came up with this fix/output:

```
print "\n".join(sorted(a.split(), key=lambda x: x >= 'a'))
```

*Output:*

```
Python
Perl
and
are
programming
languages
```

*Explanation:* sorting functions in Python are [stable](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts), which means the order of elements is preserved relative to each other if they have the same comparison key. The key function will assign a value of `True` to anything that is greater or equal to `'a'` (which is any string starting with a lowercase letter), else `False`. `False` compares smaller than `True`, so anything uppercase is moved to front, without changing the order of uppercase or lowercase words.

Comment: But this changes the order of words.

Comment: Oh ... I think I misunderstood the question. I'll correct :P Fixed.

Comment: My +1. Nice solution, even though one have to think more about how it works.  Also, the sort algorithm must be *stable* (i.e. preserving order of items with the same key).

Comment: Of course :) Please note that this is guaranteed by Python since version 2.2, see [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a homework, you should give it a tag "homework".  Anyway, the idea to use two lists is not bad.

1. Initialize the two lists to empty ones.
2. Split the input sentence using the `.split()` method of the string to get the words.
3. Use the split expression directly in the `for` loop to process the extracted words.
4. If `word` is the string variable, then `word[0]` is its first character. If it is less or equal to `'Z'` it is a capitalized word and should be appended to the wanted list.
5. Use `'\n'.join(lst)` to get the multiline string out of the list of words.

Comment: @hochl: Thanks for fixing the bug ;)

Comment: +1 I think for very long sentences using two lists might actually be faster than a sort, but I haven't tried it out.